# How to add a extention to the php.ini file

Tags: php.ini, centos6, php

Hi have Centos 6 installed and busy installing wkhtmltopdf, I only have one step left and that is to include **extension=phpwkhtmltox.so** to the php.ini file, I added it to /etc/php.ini and reloaded apache and the extention does not take effect.

I check /usr/lib64/php/modules/phpwkhtmltox.so and the file is present.

Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: Is it spelled correctly in php.ini? - should be `extension=...`

Comment: @meulop - yes it's like this in php.ini extension=phpwkhtmltox.so

Comment: It is possible that a different configuration file is being loaded. a) Check the output of `phpinfo();` for the 'Loaded Configuration File' line - see if you are actually using /etc/php.ini (or `php -i | grep php.ini` - although this isn't the same in some environments). You may want to create a new ini file under `/etc/php.d` and add your line to it (e.g. `echo "extension=phpwkhtmltox.so" > /etc/php.d/phpwkhtmltox.ini` )
. Finally, don't just add the line to the bottom of php.ini - the file is divided into sections, add it before the Module Settings.

Comment: @cyberx86 - Placing a new ini file under /etc/php.d did the trick, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When adding an extension to PHP:

1. Ensure you adding it to the correct php.ini file:

   - Check the output of `phpinfo();` for the 'Loaded Configuration File' line

     - see if you are actually using /etc/php.ini
   - Alternatively try: `php -i | grep php.ini`

     - some environments (e.g. FastCGI) may load a different config file, so this isn't always reliable
2. php.ini is an INI file - it is divided into sections (with the section names in square brackets). A directive under the wrong section may not be correctly applied. You should add extensions to the '[PHP]' section (typically the first section, it is often followed by sections for 'Module Settings')
3. PHP loads the ini files from /etc/php.d - it is good practise to add the extension from there. Create a new ini file, named after your module, containing the 'extension=' directive, and any module specific configuration options. For example:

   ```
   echo "extension=phpwkhtmltox.so" > /etc/php.d/phpwkhtmltox.ini
   ```

Of course, restart Apache/PHP after you have made the changes, and confirm that they were successful using `phpinfo();`

Comment: A note on (2) : the default php.ini file found version 5.6.9 of PHP mentions this : "Section headers (e.g. [Foo]) are also silently ignored, even though they might mean something in the future."

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux? I CANNOT get XDebug to do squat on Windows!

Comment: The above instructions are for Linux (CentOS specifically)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Fedora, added to `/etc/php.ini`

```
extension=solr.so
```

restarted `httpd` with `sudo systemctl restart httpd` but to no effect. This did it

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: your using php-fpm which is independent from your https instance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).